# Spring Security Oauth2 Authorization and Resource Server Testing with Postman

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have set up an authorization and resource server as detailed via Baeldung (sections 2 and 3): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server

However, I am trying to hit the API via Postman and am getting this:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Aug 21 08:24:17 EDT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).
```

I believe the callback URL is my issue, but I don't know what the callback URL is actually supposed to be with the defaults.

Below is my postman setup:

[image]

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Jason

Comment: where is your security configuration and your debug logs

Answer (score 1):

The callback URL is the `redirect_uri` parameter in an [OAuth 2.1 Authorization Request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05#section-4.1.1). You would have specified it in your configuration for the `RegisteredClient`:

`.redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")`

**Note:** The tutorial you followed is quite out of date. I recommend getting started using the official reference documentation's [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#developing-your-first-application) page and checking out the official [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples).